# Transpose of matrix : How this code is transposing matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I am trying to understand below code which transposes matrix on row x col

```
int transpose(int* a, int row, int col)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row*col; i++)
    {
        int old = i;
        do
        {
            old = (old%row)*col + old/row;
        }
        while(old < i)
        swap(a[i],a[old])
    }
}
```

What this line `(old = (old%row)*col + old/row)` is doing ?

Comment: Apparently, the outer loop iterates over all the elements of the matrix. However, not every element is to be exchanged with its partner; I find this a bit hard to understand. I find it a bit strange that obviously, the value of `old` cannot change as the `while` loop iterates.

Comment: It's following permutation cycles. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Comment: first and last element will remain at their position..other elements will be exchanged. What i have understood so far is for every element a[i] we try to find its old position and swap with it

Comment: Personally I found the do-while loop is the hardest part to understand...much more confusing than using modular arithmetic to find the cell index...

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is stored in a one-dimensional array of size `row*col`. The array index is `i=r*col+c`, assuming that `c` is the current column and `r` the current row. To calculate the row from the index, use integer division `r=i/col`, to get the column index, use the remainder `c=i%col`.

In the quoted line, `old` is the array index. The statement calculates a new index for the transposed element because division and remainder are not calculated with `col` as shown above but with `row`.

The `do while` loop prevents elements from being swapped twice. However I find it hard to understand and believe there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Better (more clear and probably faster) way exists but requires some memory for storing already swapped element indexes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition